# Change the paste command so it just pastes values

Tags: vba, excel

I am creating an Excel template which must be formatted in a certain way, however the people using it have a tendency to copy and paste formatting from webpages into the cells.

I've written a macro assigned to ctrl+v to change the paste command so it just pastes values, and I am attempting to use application.onkey to call the same macro using shift+insert, however while ctrl+v pastes only values, shift+insert is still performing a standard paste.

Here is the code I'm working off of:

```
Public Sub KeepDestinationFormatting()
'
' KeepDestinationFormatting Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+v
'
    ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:="Text", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:= _
        False
End Sub

Sub KeepDestinationFormatting1()
    Application.OnKey Key:="+{INSERT}", Procedure:="KeepDestinationFormatting"
End Sub
```

### EDIT

Finally got it working the way I need it to. Here's the code I used:

```
Sub Auto_Open()
    Application.OnKey Key:="+{INSERT}", Procedure:="KeepDestinationFormatting"
End Sub
Sub KeepDestinationFormatting()
    '
    ' KeepDestinationFormatting Macro
    '
    ' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+v
    '
    ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:="Text", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:= _
        False, NoHTMLFormatting:=True
End Sub
```

Comment: Btw thanks for the question - it is actually an infinitely more elegant solution to exactly the same problem that I have and for which I implemented an intricate web of procedures that disable all the possible ways of copy-pasting to prevent format contamination by careless colleagues. On the other hand it is fun to watch their faces when instead of copying/pasting stuff in, they have to read messageboxes saying "Not on my watch, sucker!"...

Comment: That is an excellent way of going about it. If I were more senior in my position I would ask for that code, lol

Answer (score 0):

The macro "does not work" because the macro *has not run*. What the macro actually does is to assign the key combo to call the procedure but since you have not run the macro, it has not been assigned. Rename the macro to *Auto_open* and then test.

Also the pasting code does not work for me, had to change it to

```
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

EDIT: Pasting the whole code:

```
Sub Auto_open()
   Application.OnKey Key:="+{INSERT}", Procedure:="KeepDestinationFormatting"
   Application.OnKey Key:="^v", Procedure:="KeepDestinationFormatting"
End Sub

Public Sub KeepDestinationFormatting()
   Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
End Sub
```

With this, you can unassign the hotkey in the macro options.

Comment: I tried that, and now I'm getting an error saying it can't find the procedure. The pasting code I have already was generated from simply recording a macro to paste values and assigning said macro to ctrl+v. Lower down I have this code: 
Public Sub KeepDestinationFormatting1()
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
End Sub
(changed procedure to KeepDestinationFormatting1 in the application.onkey line, obv). I would also note I have tried auto_open and workbook_activate for this so far with the same error each time.

Comment: You say _(changed procedure to KeepDestinationFormatting1 in the application.onkey line, obv)_ - why? What this macro does is to assign a hot key to another procedure. If I understand, now the procedure attempts to assign a hotkey to itself.

Comment: Sorry, thought it was implied I had changed the name of the sub with the application.onkey method to auto_open then named the procedure I was attempting to assign the hotkey to KeepDestinationFormatting1

Comment: Ah, ok. Btw, just pasted my own working code, you can try it out.

Comment: Unfortunately this still seems to be pasting the source formatting instead of retaining the destination formatting. Thanks anyway, though

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code. It worked without `Format:="Text"`

Replace

```
ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:="Text", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:= False
```

with

```
ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False
```

Comment: Yes that does eliminate the errors however it changes it from pasting as values to pasting from the source, which is what I am trying to eliminate in the first place

Comment: Have you a french Excel?

Comment: I have the language neutral version, purchased in America for use by a company that puts things out in multiple languages

Comment: I have asked for "french version of Excel", because I have tried your code with Format:="Texte", and it worked! Like you see, the word "Texte" is in french.

Comment: AFAIK VBA uses the default American English expressions for everything regardless of version so this is quite strange...